# Loading NetLogo headless with Rscript on Linux cluster error

Tags: java, r, netlogo

I am running Netlogo on Linux system cluster (big computer), and i am using the old version Netlogo-5.2.0, with R version 3.5 and its RPackages (RNetLogo-1.0-1 and rJava, which are compatible with Netlogo-5.2.0). When i am using the command

```
NLStart(nl.path, gui=F, nl.obj=my.netlogo1) #Creates an instance of NetLogo
```

Then it gives me this error:

```
Warning message: In `[<-`(`*tmp*`, nl.obj, value = nlo)
```

also when i start to load model

```
NLLoadModel(model.path, nl.obj=my.netlogo1)
```

it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "JobThread" java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "scala/Function0$mcV$sp"
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.run(JobThread.scala:76)
Exception in thread "JobThread" java.lang.LinkageError: org/nlogo   
/job/JobThread$$anonfun$run$1
at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.run(JobThread.scala:76)
[1] "Java-Object{java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space}"
Error in NLLoadModel(model.path, nl.obj = my.netlogo1) : 
Execution halted
```

Anyone has any ideas what is this problem and how to solve?
Thanks